# Uploading file from react to firebase fails

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, file

I'm trying to upload a file from my react website to firebase storage. File is stored in firebase but not in correct format (pdf) and I also can't open the file. As I upload the file from postman, it works.

My code for uploading the file:

```
onUploadFile = (event, authUser) => {
    const {files} = this.state;

    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    reader.onload = async (e) => {
        const url = "https://us-central1-xxxxxx-4853a.cloudfunctions.net/uploadFileFirebase";
        const fileNameResult = await fetch(e.target.result).then(res => res.blob());
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append(files[0].name, fileNameResult);
        return axios.post(url, data, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            }
        })
        .then(response => console.log('result', response));
    };

    event.preventDefault();
};
```

In node js I wrote:

```
exports.uploadFileFirebase = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {

        if (req.method !== "POST") {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: "Not allowed"
            });
        }

        const busboy = new Busboy({headers: req.headers});

        console.log(busboy);

        let uploadData = null;
        let fileName = null;
        busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
            console.log('in file');
            try {
                console.log('filename ==>');
                console.log(filename);
                fileName = filename;
                const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename);
                uploadData = {file: filepath, type: mimetype};

                file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });

        busboy.on("finish", () => {
            const bucket = gcs.bucket("xxxxxxx-4853a.appspot.com"); //TODO make map with company reference
            bucket.upload(uploadData.file, {
                uploadType: "media",
                metadata: {
                    metadata: {
                        contentType: uploadData.type
                    }
                }
            })
            .then(() => {
                return res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'file uploaded'
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    error: err.toString()
                });
            });
        });
        busboy.end(req.rawBody);
    });
});
```

The file is saved in the storage as name "blob". And has the following data:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I also proceed data-extraction from the file, data is extracted properly. How to save the file correctly with correct filename and in pdf type so that I can open the file in firebase for example.

Any thoughts?

Solution for opening the file in firebase is adding uuid to the metadata.

```
metadata: {
                    metadata: {
                        contentType: uploadData.type,
                        firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: '1f040c40-6000-48c6-8320-4fa41d9b1730 '
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

formdata.append has a third parameter for file name:

```
data.append(files[0].name, fileNameResult, files[0].name);
```

Add the name property to the blob:

```
fileNameResult.name = files[0].name
```

Before adding it to the formdata.

Comment: Then still the file is not saved under the correct filetype and I can't open it in firebase. Probably something wrong with the file action in node?

Comment: can you `console.log(fileNameResult)` and tell me what's in it?

Comment: It contains {size: 564063, type: "application/pdf"} and some _proto__: Blob object.

Comment: I added a picture in the ticket